# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while looping through ByteArray in android

Tags: android, arrays

I am trying to write a code which rotates ARGB_8888 ByteArray by 90 degrees.

While looping through the ByteArray, I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. But the index which got calculated is within the bounds of array size.

Below is the code.

```kotlin
private fun rotateByteArrayImage(
        outPutArray: ByteArray,
        rotatedArray: ByteArray,
        width: Int,
        height: Int
    ) {

        for (y in 0 until height) {
            for (x in 0 until width) {

                val destX = width - y
                val destY = x

                val srcIndex = (y * width + x) * 4
                val destIndex = (destY * height + destX) * 4
                Timber.d("srcIndex:$srcIndex, y:$y,x:$x,width:$width")

                if (srcIndex < 1228800) {

                    rotatedArray[destIndex] =
                        outPutArray[srcIndex]
                    rotatedArray[destIndex + 1] = outPutArray[srcIndex + 1]
                    rotatedArray[destIndex + 2] = outPutArray[srcIndex + 2]
                    rotatedArray[destIndex + 3] = outPutArray[srcIndex + 3]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[Code and error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8euTV.png)

Error throws at outPutArray[srcIndex].

Below is the error log.

```
D/AsciiGenerator: srcIndex:2556, y:0,x:639,width:640
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.akhilasdeveloper.asciicamera, PID: 2553
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1228800; index=1229440
        at com.akhilasdeveloper.asciicamera.util.asciigenerator.AsciiGenerator.rotateByteArrayImage(AsciiGenerator.kt:533)
        at com.akhilasdeveloper.asciicamera.util.asciigenerator.AsciiGenerator.access$rotateByteArrayImage(AsciiGenerator.kt:19)
        at com.akhilasdeveloper.asciicamera.util.asciigenerator.AsciiGenerator$imageProxyToTextBitmap$2.invokeSuspend(AsciiGenerator.kt:444)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@9da4e2b, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
```

Here we can see I'm checking for (srcIndex < 1228800) condition. But the code completely ignores it. And the log is showing value for srcIndex is srcIndex:2556.

Comment: what are the values of height and width provided to the function?

Comment: When your srcIndex is 1228799, outPutArray[srcIndex + 1] is 1228800

Comment: `val destX = width - y` this line is suspicious. Shouldn't it be `height - y - 1`?

Comment: Also you're not logging `destIndex` and since `srcIndex` is within bounds, then `destIndex` must be the problem

Comment: @Lino height is 480 and width is 640

Comment: @gioravered but the srcIndex is not 1228799. It's value is 2556.

Comment: @SergeiKozelko destX is considered as the last item of the row. That's why I had mentioned width - y

Comment: Then why are you using `if (srcIndex < 1228800)` ? Anyways this if condition doesn't make sense as it doesn't protect from crashing. I would put a conditional break point to stop when srcIndex/destIndex is out of bounds

Comment: Doing quick maths, destIndex=(639*480+640-0)*4= 1229440, so the problem is definitely with destIndex. Also if `height > width` then `destX` can be negative which is obviously wrong. You need to fix the math